# Why use non-member begin and end functions in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, container-data-type

Every standard container has a `begin` and `end` method for returning iterators for that container. However, C++11 has apparently introduced free functions called [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) which call the `begin` and `end` member functions. So, instead of writing

```
auto i = v.begin();
auto e = v.end();
```

you'd write

```
auto i = std::begin(v);
auto e = std::end(v);
```

In his talk, [Writing Modern C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-835T), Herb Sutter says that you should always use the free functions now when you want the begin or end iterator for a container. However, he does not go into detail as to *why* you would want to. Looking at the code, it saves you all of one character. So, as far as the standard containers go, the free functions seem to be completely useless. Herb Sutter indicated that there were benefits for non-standard containers, but again, he didn't go into detail.

So, the question is what exactly do the free function versions of `std::begin` and `std::end` do beyond calling their corresponding member function versions, and why would you want to use them?

Comment: It's one fewer character, save those dots for your children: http://xkcd.com/297/

Comment: I 'd somehow hate to use them because I 'd have to repeat `std::` all the time.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: Apparently you don't. See the first example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Answer (score 177, accepted):

How do you call `.begin()` and `.end()` on a C-array ?

Free-functions allow for more generic programming because they can be added afterwards, on a data-structure you cannot alter.

Comment: Except that you how you would you get `end` on a C array? They don't have their length as part of them. `begin` is as easy passing the pointer, and `end` is as easy as passing the pointer plus the length. So, `begin` seems pointless, and you can't have `end` - unless `end` can take a length to it (Herb didn't give such an example), in which case, you're _still_ not getting anything over just passing the pointer plus the length. So, `begin` and `end` are still pointless.

Comment: However, for C strings, i.e. `char*`, you could look for the `\0` character, although that is a rather slow approach compared to storing the length.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: you can have the `end` for statically declared arrays (`int foo[5]`) using template programming tricks. Once it has decayed to a pointer, you're of course out of luck.

Comment: `template<typename T, size_t N> T* end(T (&a)[N]) { return a + N; }`

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: As the others indicated, it is certainly possible to get `begin` and `end` on a C array as long as you haven't already decayed it to a pointer yourself - @Huw spells it out. As for why you'd want to: imagine that you refactored code that was using an array to use a vector (or vice-versa, for whatever reason). If you've been using `begin` and `end`, and perhaps some clever typedeffing, the implementation code won't have to change at all (except perhaps some of the typedefs).

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: Arrays are not pointers. And for everyone: For the sake of ending this ever-prominent confusion, stop referring to (some) pointers as "decayed arrays". There's no such terminology in the language, and there really isn't a use for it. Pointers are pointers, arrays are arrays. Arrays can be converted to a pointer to their first element implicitly, but the is still just a regular old pointer, with no distinction with others. Of course you can't get the "end" of a pointer, case closed.

Comment: @MatthieuM I suspect that its a linguistic problem, but whether the array is static or not is irrelevant.  You can use `end` on any C style array, static or local.  You can't use it on a pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I was intending to make a distinction between plain arrays (size known at compile time) and variable-length arrays (since gcc allows those even in C++). The latter don't work with templates.

Comment: @MatthieuM I'll admit that VLAs hadn't occurred to me.  (Things like `end()` are one of the reasons C++ didn't adopt them.  g++ is doing users a disservice to support them in C++.)

Comment: Well, other than arrays there are a large number of APIs which expose container like aspects. Obviously you can't modify a 3rd party API but you can easily write these free standing begin/end functions.

Comment: @james: In theory g++ could support VLAs with end, since the value that end should have is well defined as `&arr[0]+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arg)`. Addmittedly, though that would require special magic treatment of an std::end overload, but it could still be done. Special compiler magic is required for some library parts already...

Comment: @KevinCathcart: Computing the `end` is possible, but deducing the array type is not. It is not possible for a function to take an array as parameter. The closest (and only possibility to emulate this afaik) is to have a template taking a reference to an array (as shown by @Huw), however this requires a compile-time known size :/

Comment: That is why such a function would need special compiler support to bypass the limitation. I do agree that there is no way to implement it without either special compiler magic, or some form of non-standard extention. Perhaps G++ could reuse the parameter forward declaration extention. Thus `template<typename T> T* end(size_t N; T (&a)[N]) {return a+N;}`. That would be treated as having one paramter in pretty much all respects, although in the generated code it would actually have two parameters, with the compiler supplying `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)` at the call site (unless inlined of course).

Comment: @GManNickG The word decay might not be in the language standard but I'm pretty sure everyone understands that it refers to how an array is treated when it is passed to a function.

The same code that would work (e.g. begin(c_array)) within main() where the sizeof the c_array is known will *not* work in an function which is passed the c_array as a parameter.  Which I'm sure you are aware of.

The compiler will give a diagnostic something like:
`error: cannot build range expression with array function parameter 'c' since parameter with array type 'int []' is treated as pointer type 'int *'`

Comment: I don't know if i am right, using a non member function is more object oriented(encapsulation), isn't?

Comment: @Lexshard: So, the principle of least privilege applied to C++ translates to "Prefer non-member, non-friends, functions" because, indeed, those functions are least privilege and therefore are agnostic to the internal representation (better encapsulation). This principle is for the **writer** of the function, the users don't really get to choose. Here, the use of free-functions is for another reason: since C++ does not offer the ability to add member functions to built-in types (such as arrays), only free-functions can be used for them.

Answer (score 37):

Using the `begin` and `end` free functions adds one layer of indirection.  Usually that is done to allow more flexibility.

In this case I can think of a few uses.

The most obvious use is for C-arrays (not c pointers).

Another is when trying to use a standard algorithm on a non-conforming container (ie the container is missing a `.begin()` method).  Assuming you can't just fix the container, the next best option is to overload the `begin` function.  Herb is suggesting you always use the `begin` function to promote uniformity and consistency in your code. Instead of having to remember which containers support method `begin` and which need function `begin`.

As an aside, the next C++ rev should copy D's *[pseudo-member notation](http://books.google.com/books?id=bn7GNq6fiIUC&lpg=PT224&ots=67-2Ig1Qz4&dq=pseudo-member%20notation&pg=PT224#v=onepage&q=pseudo-member%20notation&f=false)*.  If `a.foo(b,c,d)` is not defined it instead tries `foo(a,b,c,d)`.  It's just a little syntactic sugar to help us poor humans who prefer subject then verb ordering.

Comment: The _pseudo-member notation_ looks like C#/.Net _extension methods_. They do come in useful for various situations though - like all features - can be prone to 'abuse'.

Comment: The pseudo-member notation is a boon for coding with Intellisense; hitting "a." shows relevant verbs, freeing up brain power from memorizing lists, and helping to discover relevant API functions can help prevent duplicating functionality, without having to shoehorn non-member functions into classes.

Comment: There are proposals to get that into C++, which use the term Unified Function Call Syntax (UFCS).

Comment: Next C++ rev refers to? Was that implemented?

Answer (score 36):

Consider the case when you have library that contain class:

```
class SpecialArray;
```

it has 2 methods:

```
int SpecialArray::arraySize();
int SpecialArray::valueAt(int);
```

to iterate over it's values you need to inherit from this class and define `begin()` and `end()` methods for cases when

```
auto i = v.begin();
auto e = v.end();
```

But if you always use

```
auto i = begin(v);
auto e = end(v);
```

you can do this:

```
template <>
SpecialArrayIterator begin(SpecialArray & arr)
{
  return SpecialArrayIterator(&arr, 0);
}

template <>
SpecialArrayIterator end(SpecialArray & arr)
{
  return SpecialArrayIterator(&arr, arr.arraySize());
}
```

where `SpecialArrayIterator` is something like:

```
class SpecialArrayIterator
{
   SpecialArrayIterator(SpecialArray * p, int i)
    :index(i), parray(p)
   {
   }
   SpecialArrayIterator operator ++();
   SpecialArrayIterator operator --();
   SpecialArrayIterator operator ++(int);
   SpecialArrayIterator operator --(int);
   int operator *()
   {
     return parray->valueAt(index);
   }
   bool operator ==(SpecialArray &);
   // etc
private:
   SpecialArray *parray;
   int index;
   // etc
};
```

now `i` and `e` can be legally used for iteration and accessing of values of SpecialArray

Comment: This should not include the `template<>` lines. You are declaring a new function overload, not specializing a template.

Comment: I'm confused what overloading the increment and decrement operators is doing since the functions are just prototypes.

Answer (score 18):

To answer your question, the free functions begin() and end() by default do nothing more than call the container's member .begin() and .end() functions. From `<iterator>`, included automatically when you use any of the standard containers like `<vector>`, `<list>`, etc., you get:

```
template< class C > 
auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
template< class C > 
auto begin( const C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

The second part of you question is why prefer the free functions if all they do is call the member functions anyway. That really depends on what kind of object `v` is in your example code. If the type of v is a standard container type, like `vector<T> v;` then it doesn't matter if you use the free or member functions, they do the same thing. If your object `v` is more generic, like in the following code:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T& v) {
  auto i = v.begin();     
  auto e = v.end(); 
  for(; i != e; i++) { /* .. do something with i .. */ } 
}
```

Then using the member functions breaks your code for T = C arrays, C strings, enums, etc. By using the non-member functions, you advertise a more generic interface that people can easily extend. By using the free function interface:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T& v) {
  auto i = begin(v);     
  auto e = end(v); 
  for(; i != e; i++) { /* .. do something with i .. */ } 
}
```

The code now works with T = C arrays and C strings. Now writing a small amount of adapter code:

```
enum class color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
static color colors[]  = { color::RED, color::GREEN, color::BLUE };
color* begin(const color& c) { return begin(colors); }
color* end(const color& c)   { return end(colors); }
```

We can get your code to be compatible with iterable enums too. I think Herb's main point is that using the free functions is just as easy as using the member functions, and it gives your code backward compatibility with C sequence types and forward compatibility with non-stl sequence types (and future-stl types!), with low cost to other developers.

Comment: Nice examples. I wouldn't take an `enum` or any other fundamental type by reference, though; they will be cheaper to copy than they are to indirect to.

Comment: Kinda outdated but have in mind that strings now have begin() and end() methods too

Answer (score 10):

One benefit of `std::begin` and `std::end` is that they serve as extension points
for implementing standard interface for external classes.

If you'd like to use `CustomContainer` class with range-based for loop or template
function which expects `.begin()` and `.end()` methods, you'd obviously have to
implement those methods.

If the class does provide those methods, that's not a problem. When it doesn't,
you'd have to modify it*.

This is not always feasible, for example when using external library, esspecially
commercial and closed source one.

In such situations, `std::begin` and `std::end` come in handy, since one can provide
iterator API without modifying the class itself, but rather overloading free functions.

**Example:** suppose that you'd like to implement `count_if` function that takes a container
instead of a pair of iterators. Such code might look like this:

```
template<typename ContainerType, typename PredicateType>
std::size_t count_if(const ContainerType& container, PredicateType&& predicate)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    return std::count_if(begin(container), end(container),
                         std::forward<PredicateType&&>(predicate));
}
```

Now, for any class you'd like to use with this custom `count_if`, you only have
to add two free functions, instead of modifying those classes.

Now, C++ has a  mechanisim called [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)
(ADL), which makes such approach even more flexible.

In short, ADL means, that when a compiler resolves an unqualified function (i. e.
function without namespace, like `begin` instead of `std::begin`), it will also
consider functions declared in namespaces of its arguments. For example:

```
namesapce some_lib
{
    // let's assume that CustomContainer stores elements sequentially,
    // and has data() and size() methods, but not begin() and end() methods:

    class CustomContainer
    {
        ...
    };
}

namespace some_lib
{    
    const Element* begin(const CustomContainer& c)
    {
        return c.data();
    }

    const Element* end(const CustomContainer& c)
    {
        return c.data() + c.size();
    }
}

// somewhere else:
CustomContainer c;
std::size_t n = count_if(c, somePredicate);
```

In this case, it doesn't matter that qualified names are `some_lib::begin` and `some_lib::end`
- since `CustomContainer` is in `some_lib::` too, compiler will use those overloads in `count_if`.

That's also the reason for having `using std::begin;` and `using std::end;` in `count_if`.
This allows us to use unqualified `begin` and `end`, therefore allowing for ADL **and**
allowing compiler to pick `std::begin` and `std::end` when no other alternatives are found.

We can eat the cookie and have the cookie - i. e. have a way to provide custom implementation
of `begin`/`end` while the compiler can fall back to standard ones.

Some notes:

- For the same reason, there are other similar functions: `std::rbegin`/`rend`,
  `std::size` and `std::data`.
- As other answers mentions, `std::` versions have overloads for naked arrays. That's useful,
  but is simply a special case of what I've described above.
- Using `std::begin` and friends is particularly good idea when writing template code,
  because this makes those templates more generic. For non-template you might just
  as well use methods, when applicable.

*P. S. I'm aware that this post is nearly 7 years old. I came across it because I wanted to
answer a question which was marked as a duplicate and discovered that no answer here mentions ADL.*

Comment: Good answer, particularly explaining ADL overtly, rather than leaving it up to the imagination like everyone else did - even when *they were showing it in action!*

Answer (score 5):

Whereas the non-member functions don't provide any benefit for the standard containers, using them enforces a more consistent and flexible style. If you at some time want to extend an existing non-std container class, you'd rather define overloads of the free functions, instead of altering the existing class's definition. So for non-std containers they are very useful and always using the free functions makes your code more flexible in that you can substitute the std container by a non-std container more easily and the underlying container type is more transparent to your code as it supports a much wider variety of container implementations.

But of course this always has to be weighted properly and over abstraction is not good either. Although using the free functions is not that much of an over-abstraction, it nevertheless breaks compatibility with C++03 code, which at this young age of C++11 might still be an issue for you.

Comment: In C++03, you can just use `boost::begin()`/`end()`, so there's no real incompatibility :)

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz Well, boost dependency is not always an option (and is quite an overkill if used only for `begin/end`). So I would regard that an incompatibility to pure C++03, too. But like said, it is a rather small (and getting smaller) incompatibility, as C++11 (at least `begin/end` in particular) is getting more and more adoption, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the benefit is in code that is generalized such that it's container agnostic. It can operate on a `std::vector`, an array, or a range without changes to the code itself.

Additionally, containers, even non-owned containers can be retrofitted such that they can also be used agnostically by code using non-member range based accessors.

See [here](https://topanswers.xyz/cplusplus?q=952#a1130) for more detail.