# sorting error: type name is not allowed

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I encountered several compiler errors while writing this codes to sort my structure of array. Can anyone tells me what're the mistakes I did with my codes? These are the errors shown in the compiler and all errors come from

```
std::sort(player.begin(), player.end(), &player);
```

1.error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' : expects 3 arguments - 1 provided

2.error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided

3.error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union

4.error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union

5.error C2275: 'player' : illegal use of this type as an expression

6.IntelliSense: type name is not allowed

My codes are as below.

```
struct player
{
  char name[31];
  int num_attempt;
  time_t time_elapsed;
  bool operator ()(const player & lhs, const player & rhs)
  {return lhs.num_attempt < rhs.num_attempt; 
   return lhs.time_elapsed <rhs.time_elapsed;}
}player_data[5]

std::sort(player.begin(), player.end(), &player);
```

Comment: `player.begin(), player.end(), &player` makes no sense what so ever, `player` is a type, not an object. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Two problems: player is the name of the array's type, not the array. You probably intend player_data, but to make that work, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595285/cannot-use-begin-or-end-on-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::sort` expects that its first two arguments are random-access iterators to the beginning and and of the sequence to be sorted.  You appear to be calling methods on a type name, which is a syntax error.  (If `begin` and `end` were static methods on the type `player`, the correct syntax would be `player::begin()`).  You should replace `player.begin()` and `player.end()` with something that returns iterators into a sequence; maybe something like `std::begin(player_data)` and `std::end(player_data)`?

Also, `std::sort` expects a comparator object, rather than a pointer to something.  Taking the address of a type, as your example does, clearly won't work, but since every one of your objects is a comparator, you could just use `player_data[0]`.

So a call to `std::sort` that might work for you would be

```
std::sort(std::begin(player_data), std::end(player_data), player_data[0]);
```