# Iterator or std::iota with regular C++ Array?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, iteration, iota

Is there a way to achieve the same effect as this,

```
std::list<int> l(10);
std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), -4);
```

With a regular `int a[]`?

Or, is the following the only way around:

```
for (iterator itr = begin; itr != end; ++itr)
    /* ... visit *itr here ... */
```

Comment: just `std::iota( std::begin(a), std::end(a), -4 )`. I mean, if the latter was "the only way around", how would you get those iterators to loop with `for` in the first place?

Comment: Is that O(1) ? Right?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Iterators to a plain array are just pointers. This seems like a dupe of [Cannot use .begin() or .end() on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595285/cannot-use-begin-or-end-on-an-array)

Comment: ? What do you mean?

Comment: You asked whether you can use a raw array with algorithms taking iterators, and then say 'or do I have to do it this way... using iterators'. You were shown how to get iterators to a raw array. Such iterators are just pointers, because what else could they be?. `iota` just assigns progressive values to each element, so that's O(1), and why would that be any different for a raw array than it is for an `std::list`? It's overall not clear exactly what you're asking or why.

Comment: `std::begin` and `std::end` for that array are equivalent to `&a[0]` and `&a[number_of_elements]` (which you could use since forever). It's not a coincidence that the interface of iterators has the same appearance as the interface of pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 added [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). Since then there is no difference:

```
std::list<int> l(10);
std::iota(std::begin(l),std::end(l), -4);
int a[10];
std::iota(std::begin(a),std::end(a), -4);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### tl;dr: Wrap your array in a "span".

@idclev463035818's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63739496/1593077) is the most straightforward thing to do. However, if you want to treat your array as a standard-library container in multiple contexts, consider wrapping the raw array in a span, like so:

```
auto a_ = std::span{a};
```

spans are lightweight reference-types to contiguous storage. They don't own their data, so you're not copying the array or anything. You can read more about spans here:

[What is a "span" and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1593077)

Anyway, now you can write:

```
std::iota(a_.begin(), a_.end(), -4);
for(x : a_) { do_stuff_with(x); }
auto c = std::ranges::count_if(a_, [](auto x) { return x > 3; });
```

and so on. Perhaps more importantly, the array ["decays" into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) if you pass it to another function, and then you can no longer use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` on it; the span *can* be passed around, so it's more robust.

However - `std::span` is only in the standard beginning with C++20. Before that you can use the span implementation in the [gsl-lite library](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite), for example.

Comment: for range based for loops a span is not necessary (https://godbolt.org/z/9ea1qE)  otherwise nice answer. And nice user name :P