# Constrution of std::vector from a pair of iterators. What element constructors are allowed to be called?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdvector

In [[vector.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.cons) there is the `std::vector` constructor (emphasis mine):

> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
>   constexpr vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>                    const Allocator& = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Constructs a vector equal to the range `[first, last)`, using the specified allocator.
>
> *Complexity*: Makes only *N* calls to the **copy constructor** of `T` (where *N* is the distance between `first` and `last`) and no reallocations if iterators `first` and `last` are of forward, bidirectional, or random access categories. It makes order *N* calls to the **copy constructor** of `T` and order log*N* reallocations if they are just input iterators.

However, the following example compiles fine in GCC, Clang (using libc++), and at least in the version of MSVC hosted in godbolt.org.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

class A
{
private:
  std::complex<double> const x;

public:
  A() = delete;
  A(A const &) = delete;
  explicit A(std::complex<double> const x_) : x(x_) {}
};

void f(std::size_t Size)
{
std::vector<std::complex<double>> v(Size);

std::vector<A> u(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

i. e. the appropriate constructor is chosen instead of the deleted copy constructor. Can I rely on such behavior? Am I misunderstanding the standard wording?

Comment: Why not `v.begin(), v.end()` ??

Comment: @DumbCoder the code above is more generic as it works also for C-style arrays

Comment: @DumbCoder, see [this question - "Why use non-member begin and end functions in C++11?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593086/why-use-non-member-begin-and-end-functions-in-c11).

Comment: @DumbCoder I tend to use the free functions because they also work e.g. with `std::valarray` and plain arrays.

Comment: @bartop I am aware of that but why in this case ? That was my query.

Comment: I would say wording issue, as it is not necessary **copy** constructor.

Comment: @DumbCoder Because the OP never said from where the pair of iterators shall come from. Because he's talking in the general case (and C-style arrays are in). Because the code shown is just an example and the way to get the iterators is not really the question here... :)

Comment: This is subtly different to the duplicate, as `A` is only *explicitly* convertible from `std::complex<double>`